# How To Directly Call Support Data From Ruby on Rails Active Admin Database Tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, crud

I am having problems understanding and getting access to support data within the database. One of the objects created from active admin was a model called 'interests'. Interests is an object I can call within the application (such as controller) directly. However, I have a need to get access to what I am guessing is basically support data that I believe Active Admin also created called 'interests_users'. The reason why is because it links users to the interests data which is very useful. See below schema.rb

```
create_table "interests", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "name"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false

create_table "interests_users", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
t.integer "interest_id", null: false
t.integer "user_id",     null: false
t.index ["interest_id"], name: "index_interests_users_on_interest_id"
t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_interests_users_on_user_id"
```

As an example, I can get access to the interest table within my application code by just doing this

```
@interest = Interest.all
```

Then I can access that data within my Views so I can actually work with that data but whatever I try I cannot get access to the interests_users data. If I try things like

```
@interest_users = InterestsUsers.All
```

I get errors such as 'uninitialized constant PagesController'. Anyhow, I am new to Rails and I believe I lack a lot of fundamental knowledge when it comes to understanding proper techniques to get data from database to the HTML. Any direct help with this problem would be awesome as I am pretty stumped as of now.

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

  def discovery

    @aoks = Micropost.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 12)
  end

  def home
    if user_signed_in?
      @post = current_user.posts.build
      @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
    else
      @******
      @user_count = User.count
      @user_all = User.all
      @interest = Interest.all
      @interest2 = Interest.first; @interest.users.    ——problem!
      #@interest_table = Interest
      #@interest_users = InterestsUsers.All
      #interests_users.find_each do |user|.     ——problem!
      #  @interest_user = user
      #end 
    end
```

```
class Interest < ApplicationRecord.     ##models/interest.rb
  has_and_belongs_to_many :user
end
```

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: The 'interests_users' tables that was auto-generated is a join table and is used to store the relationship data between users and interests. When you say you want to access the details in the table, do you really want to access the users associated with an interest and visa versa?

Comment: If so try `@interest = Interest.first; @interest.users`

Comment: Hey Mark, I really appreciate your time. First of all, yeah I do basically just want to access the data to find what users are associated with what interests.

Comment: You're calling 'users' on a group of interests, rather than a single one

Comment: Can you paste the code thats triggering the error, or just your whole controller + 2 model files please

Comment: Read through https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association as it's pretty much what you're trying to do

Comment: Mark, I just want to say your original answers was the solution I was looking for. I did not quit understand it the first time I looked at it but then looking at it again and trying it out it did work. Thanks so much! You definitely saved me many many hours of just going around in circles!

Comment: No worries! Happy you got there :)